# Does spell vamp work with Kayle's E?

Tags: league-of-legends

If I buy `Hextech Revolver` and I use **Kayle**'s <kbd>E</kbd> to hit my opponents, will the `spell vamp` work that way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Kayle**'s E is rather complicated. Fundamentally, it has 2 parts: the bonus Magic Damage dealt when attacking, and the splash damage centered on her attack target (who also suffers from the splash).

What this means is that each main hit of Kayle's auto-attack (assuming E is active) will trigger as an on-hit ability (Rageblade stacks, lifesteal, etc.), while the splash hit of **Kayle**'s auto-attack behaves as a spell (proccing Rylai's, triggering spellvamp, etc.).

So while **Kayle**'s E *will* work with both Rylai's and Spellvamp items, it is **only the splash** (that is, the AoE portion) that triggers it, meaning Rylai's slow is diminished, and spell vamp is less effective (as with all AoE abilities).

Comment: So, what you're trying to tell me is that, in this case life steal is more effective than spell vamp?

Comment: @Fabián Depends on how much AP and AD you're packing. Lifesteal will get 100% of Kayle's AD, but if you're hitting at least 3 targets, you're also getting 100% of the splash damage you're doing. (And of course, the more AP you have, the more life returned, which might be more than equivalent Lifesteal if you're building straight AP)

Comment: also noteworthy is: splash is applied on-attack, additional damage to main target is applied on-hit, meaning when you are blinded the health you get from lifesteal is nullified, but the spellvamp will still leech, this means there are 3 parts of kayle 's e and not just two ;)